# Trying to use a jar originally from tomcat 6/java 6 in tomcat 7/java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I used the following class (from a jar file) in a tomcat6/java6 project: 
ws.UserAuthenticationService

I created a new java project (eclipse/tomcat7/java7) and added the above jar to the build path.

When i tried to use it in the code (added correct import) i got the following error in runtime:

> Apr 17, 2013 7:13:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [stdadmin.servlet.Controler] in context with path [/stdadmin] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ws.UserAuthenticationService
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>       at stdadmin.servlet.Controler.userAuthenticated(Controler.java:116)
>       at stdadmin.servlet.Controler.handleAuth(Controler.java:102)
>       at stdadmin.servlet.Controler.forwardToMatchingJSP(Controler.java:65)
>       at stdadmin.servlet.Controler.doPost(Controler.java:53)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Is there a way to know ***why*** the class is not found ?
Is there compatibility to use java6 jars in java7 ?

Comment: Java 7 is generally backwards compatible. Maybe you didn't add the jar correctly. Can you give some more details?

Comment: For your bottom line: you're using a Tomcat 6 jar in a Tomcat 7 installation, not a Java 6 jar in a Java 7 installation (Tomcat 7 can run happily using Java 6 or 7). Looks like the jar is not in your build path as expected. Make sure this library is inside *WEB-INF/lib* folder of your web project (and by *make sure* I mean to check if the file exists in the generated war).

Comment: One more thing: Tomcat is not Java EE application server at all, is just a servlet container. Java EE compliant application server examples are GlassFish v3, JBoss AS 7...

Comment: The most common reason for classNotFoundException : the jar is not in the WEB-INF/lib ! problem solved thank ppl !

Comment: Never mix up files from different versions of Tomcat, It's possible that a Tomcat 7 files is trying to call a Tomcat 7 version of a class in your Tomcat 6 jar, and gets the Tomcat 6 version. But the Tomcat 6 version tries to call a class that was deleted in Tomcat 7.